# openssl for windows and powershell PFX to PEM

Tags: powershell, ssl, openssl, pem, pfx

### Goal

Ok so I have [openssl for windows](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/)  in a directory and I am trying to get a script running that will let me take a pfx file that contains every thing I need and split it in to all the files i need separately. This will allow for easy upload to AWS IAM cert store later.

### Problem

I will post what I have at the bottom, the only issue is the commands are not passing to openssl.exe correctly for some reason, however if you copy the output it creates at "$argu" and run the arguments against the .exe manually it works perfectly. I can not for the life of me work out its issue.

### Update

I have attempted to use the following two methods to invoke the .exe but it appears the arguments string is not converting correctly and an extra apostrophe is been added to the arguments causing openssl to fail.

Attempt 1

```
& $opssl $argu
```

Attempt 2 is below in my updated code.
OpenSSL.exe throws the following error when using option 1. Is there a better way to create the string before passing it to the .exe?

## Error

```
openssl:Error: 'pkcs12 -in 'E:\certs\openssl\domain.com.au\domain.com.au-PFX.pfx' -passin pass:(removed) -nokeys -cacerts -out 'domain.com.au-PFX-20160517\domain.com.au-PFX-CA-Cert.pem'' is an invalid command.
```

### Script

```
    $exedir = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    cd $exedir
    #Powershell to use open SSL to convert a pfx to pem 
    Write-output "Please enter full path and PFX file" 
    $cert = read-host
    
    Write-output "Please enter password for you PFX" 
    $pfxpass = read-host
    
    
    $date = Get-date -Format "yyyMMdd"
    $certDirf = Get-item "$cert" | select basename
    $string = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($cert)
    $string2 = $string.Substring(0)
    $certDir = $string2
    $opssl = "$exedir\openssl.exe"
    Write-output "$certDir"
    
    $opssltest = If (Test-Path $exedir\openssl.exe){
      Write-host "found OpenSSL.exe"
      }
      Else
      {
      write-host "couldn't find openSSL.exe"
      } 
      Invoke-Command -scriptblock { $opssltest }
    
    
    
Function Get-Key {
if (!(test-path $certdir-$date)){mkdir $certdir-$date -force}
cd $exedir
$Argu = "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nocerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-encrypted-key.pem' -nodes"
Write-host "$argu"
Start-Process -FilePath "$opssl" -ArgumentList "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nocerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-encrypted-key.pem' -nodes"
Write-host "encrypted key written"
sleep 1
$Argu = "rsa -in $certdir-$date\$certdir-encrypted-key.pem -out $certdir-$date\$certdir-key.pem"
Write-host "$argu"
Start-Process -FilePath "$opssl" -ArgumentList "rsa -in '$certdir-$date\$certdir-encrypted-key.pem' -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-key.pem'"
Write-host "Key Un-encrypted"
Menu
}

Function Get-Cert {
if (!(test-path $certdir-$date)){mkdir $certdir-$date -force}
cd $exedir
$Argu = "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nokeys -clcerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-Cert.pem'"
Write-host "$Argu"
Start-Process -FilePath "$opssl" -ArgumentList "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nokeys -clcerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-Cert.pem'"
Write-host "Cert exported"
Menu
}

Function Get-CACert {
if (!(test-path $certdir-$date)){mkdir $certdir-$date -force}
cd $exedir
$Argu = "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nokeys -cacerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-CA-Cert.pem'"
Write-host "$argu"
$type = "pkcs12"
Start-Process -FilePath "$opssl" -ArgumentList "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nokeys -cacerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-CA-Cert.pem'"
Write-host "CA-Cert exported"
Menu
}



Function Menu{
[int]$xMenuChoiceA = 0
while ( $xMenuChoiceA -lt 1 -or $xMenuChoiceA -gt 4 ){
Write-host "All exports are in PEM format except for privet keys"
Write-host "1. Export privet key"
Write-host "2. Export Certificate"
Write-host "3. Export Ca Certificaet"
write-host "4. Exit"
[Int]$xMenuChoiceA = read-host "Please enter an option 1 to 4..." }
Switch( $xMenuChoiceA ){
  1{Get-Key}
  2{Get-Cert}
  3{Get-CACert}
  4{Exit}
}
}
Menu
```

Comment: I ended up building this up over time, https://bitbucket.org/LucasSymons/pfxtopempfxtopem/wiki/Home

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke a native application (not a PowerShell commandlet or script), just say so:

```
cmd.exe /C echo ohai
```

or

```
& 'cmd.exe' /C echo ohai
```

You can use `&` operator to indicate that you want your variable interpreted as command name. Perfect when you don't know a file path until execution time.

```
$arguments = "pkcs12 -in '$cert' -passin pass:$pfxpass -nocerts -out '$certdir-$date\$certdir-encrypted-key.pem' -nodes"

& $opssl $arguments
```

There has to be a way to make your example work, but that's a .NET question. Just use PowerShell to do the work for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the suggestion. I have tested it out and i think i have found the error. when passing the arguments to the .exe there is an extra ' in there. I get the below error, any idea how to remove it?         `openssl:Error: 'rsa`